# Django template: How to use variables in an {% if x == y %} statement?

Tags: python, django, templates

In a Djgano template I want to include a {% if x == y %} statement where both x and y are variables as follows:

```
<title>Category: {{category_id}}</title>
<select name="category_id">
         {% for category in categories %}
            <option value="{{category.id}}" 
            {% if category.id is category_id %} selected {% endif %}>{{category.id}} : {{category.name}}</option>
        {% endfor %}
```

The {{category_id}} variable is set and in the context. It displays correctly if places outside of the {% if %}, but inside the {% if %} bracket does not work.

```
{% if category.id == category_id %}
```

does not work. I assume that in this case category_id is simply read as a non-variable.

```
{% if category.id is {{category_id}} %}
{% if category.id == {{category_id}} %}
```

Gives an error:
"Could not parse the remainder: '{{category_id}}' from '{{category_id}}'"

```
{% if category.id is category.id %}
```

Works, of course, but of course that means that everything in the loop will become "selected".

Comment: `{% if category.id == category_id %}` definitely *should* work provided the variables are properly stored in the context. Make sure they are. It is possible that you are not actually storing the `id` in the variable `category_id`, but something else instead that displays correctly in the template because it is parsed to a string as the `id`. Then, `{% if category.id == category_id %}` is always `False`.  Just a thought...

Comment: Thank you.

I am guessing that you are correct. The id must have, at some point, changed to a str() maybe?

Anyway, I worked around it and the old way is deleted, so I can not easily just test to see.